# JQuery/Bootstrap: close and open the same modal to refresh the content, which is generated dynamically

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have a products page and once user click on a product I open up a modal generating dynamically the content. In the modal itself there are other products so when the user click there I would like to close the modal and re-open it in order to refresh the content - so once the modal reload the old content should be deleted and replaced with the new one.

Below a simplified version:

```
    <html lang="en">

<head>

<!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="js/ajax.js"></script>

<script>
function openmodal(id){
var id=id;
var other="<a onclick='openmodal(1)' style='cursor:pointer'>product 1</a><a onclick='openmodal(2)' style='cursor:pointer'>product 2</a><a onclick='openmodal(3)' style='cursor:pointer' >product 3</a>";
$('#item_modal').modal('show');
$("#target_title").text(id);
$("#target_other").append(other);
}

</script>

</head>
<body>
<a onclick="openmodal(1)" style="cursor:pointer">product 1</a>
<a onclick="openmodal(2)" style="cursor:pointer">product 2</a>
<a onclick="openmodal(3)" style="cursor:pointer">product 3</a>

<div id="item_modal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">

<!-- Modal content-->
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-body">
<h1 id="target_title"></h1>
<div id="target_other">

</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>

<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/classie.js"></script>
<script src="js/cbpAnimatedHeader.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Any help?
Thanks
Best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rb2fsv16/)**

Since you are **hiding** and **showing** on the same instance it will create one more backdrop but will not be able to show the `modal` again. So you either can have a `setTimeout` before showing the `modal` with a minimal time interval, *which will be inefficient as a backdrop will not be destroyed* or just make use of `shown.bs.modal` method and hide `modal` before showing as below:

```
function openmodal(id){
    var id=id;
    //No need to hide here
    $('#item_modal').modal('show');
    $("#target_title").text(id);
}

$("#item_modal").on("shown.bs.modal",function(){
   //will be executed everytime #item_modal is shown
   $(this).hide().show(); //hide first and then show here
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

To have a `fadeIn` and `fadeOut` effect here is the little trick but you might feel its bit `slow` and its upto you to opt this solution or not

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/rb2fsv16/2/)**

```
function openmodal(id){
    var id=id;
    var other="<a onclick='openmodal(1)' style='cursor:pointer'>product 1</a><a onclick='openmodal(2)' style='cursor:pointer'>product 2</a><a onclick='openmodal(3)' style='cursor:pointer' >product 3</a>";
    $('#item_modal').fadeOut("slow",function(){
        $(this).modal('hide')
    }).fadeIn("slow",function(){
        $("#target_title").text(id);
        $("#target_other").html(other);
        $(this).modal('show')
    });
}
```

You can now remove `shown.bs.modal` part as it is handled in the `function` itself

Comment: Thanks Guruprasad. As I think you are saying, the issue with the code you posted is that the old content doesn't get destroyed, so by using "append" I basically add the new content after the old one. Which is not what i would want. What i want is that the old content gets destroyed and gets replaced with the new one.

Comment: So what happens when you click the link inside `modal`.. On next show does that links inside modal still exist? and can you please let me know the reason to destroy the `modal` completely and why this solution is not what you are looking for?

Comment: I edited the code in my question so that you can see what happens: basically the old content stays there and the new content only gets appended.  The reason why i need the old content to be destroyed is: I have a list of products on first modal, once you click on one of the product I want to change the the list of products on the new modal (replacing the old list).

Comment: Thanks, that perfectly does the trick! Would it be possible to have between the hide and show a basic fade transition? I tried setTimeout but didn't work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can destroy the modal object before calling the same modal next time. The object is destroyed when the modal is hidden.

```
$('body').on('hidden.bs.modal', '.modal', function () {
  $(this).removeData('bs.modal');
});
```

Comment: Thanks Gautam. The issue with the code you posted is that the old content doesn't get destroyed and the new only gets added to the old one (but doesn't replace it). I edited my code to show the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add the html function instead of append. Because append always adds the row . Declare a empty variable like

```
var dynamic = "";

dynamic += 'your html here';
$('#table_id').html(dynamic);
```